# Align a Figcaption text which is in Absolute position below an Image which is in a DIV

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to make a gallery and need some help with align multiple text in the center of the images

HTML:

```
  <div class="gallery">
    <figure class="gallery-item">
     <a target="_blank" href="./Event/1.jpg">
     <img class="thumbnail" src="./Event/1.jpg" width="500" height="281"></a>
     <figcaption class="comment"><B>Text</b></figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.comment {
 position: absolute;
 color: #F04D46;
}
```

EDIT: Fixed the Typo, still same problem tho.

Comment: It seems like typo question. You mess a letters here: `<figcatpion`

Comment: Verified: it was just that typo.